# Как удалить Dict из листа не зная где он, но при этом я знаю его содержимое - python3

Tags: python, массивы, list, dict

Возможно ли удалить элемент (dict) из листа при том, что я не знаю где иммено он, но я знаю его содержимое?

Comment: А можете переформулировать вопрос или привести пример, сейчас не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: обратите внимание вот сюда: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простейшем случае задача решается в одну строку методом `remove` который принимает образец для удаления. Если совпадений будет несколько - удалится первый найденный элемент:

```
lst = [{"y": 2}, {"x": 1}, 5]
del_item = {"x": 1}
lst.remove(del_item)
print(lst) # [{'y': 2}, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение в лоб для понимания

```py
d = [1, 2, 3, {"a":"valueA"}, "b", "a", {"B":"valueB"}] 
index_to_delete = None
value_to_delete = "valueA"
for count, i in enumerate(d):
    if isinstance(i, dict) and value_to_delete in i.values():
        index_to_delete = count
        break

if index_to_delete: del d[index_to_delete]
```

С проверкой, что это действительно словарь, для неоднородного списка.